# Find page numbers where given text occurs

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I have keywords or keyphrases that each occur one or more times in a multi-page document. For each keyphrase, how do I find the page number of each page that it occurs it?

Answer (score 1):

Yepp, it can be done much easier with the `findText()` method:

```
app.findTextPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
app.findTextPreferences.findWhat = app.selection[0].contents;

var founds = app.activeDocument.findText(); // get all founds

// get page numbers from the founds without duplicates
var obj = {}, numbers = [];
while (f = founds.shift()) {
    var num = f.parentTextFrames[0].parentPage.name;
    if (!(num in obj)) {
        obj[num] = '';
        numbers.push(+num);
    }
}

numbers.sort(function (a,b) {return a-b}); // sort the numbers

alert(numbers.join(', ')); // result
```

As for the documentation, you can see a lot of examples of Extendscript scripts on Stackoverflow. Good description of the InDesign API is here:

https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest

Answer (score 0):

This script takes the currently selected text, uses it as a search phrase, loops through all pages, collects the page numbers of those that contain the search phrase, formats the resulting array as `"1, 2, 3, 4"`, prints it on an alert dialog, and copies it into the clipboard, so the user can paste the resulting string where he wants.

Note, I found InDesign's scripting engine to be incompatible with any non-ancient Javascript feature, hence the C-style for loops. InDesign's scripting environment also has something called `findText` and `findGrep`, which may have been useful, but I failed to find their documentation and I failed to get them to do what I wanted. Your mileage might vary.

```
// Used to let the user define what text to search for by selecting text
function getSelectedText() {
    return app.selection[0].contents
}

// Used to give user access to the result of the script via the clipboard
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    var frame = app.activeDocument.pages[0].textFrames.add();
    frame.geometricBounds = [0,0,200,100];
    frame.contents = text;
    frame.parentStory.texts.everyItem().select();
    app.copy();
    $.sleep(300); // just in case
    frame.remove();
}

// Used for deduplicating the results
Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (this[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Given a targetPhrase, returns an array containing every page number it
// occurs in, in ascending order.
function findPageNumbersOfOccurancesOfText(targetPhrase) {
  // Create an array to store results
  var results = [];
  // Loop through each spread in the document
  for (var s = 0; s < app.activeDocument.spreads.length; s++) {
      var spread = app.activeDocument.spreads[s];
      
      // Loop through each page within the spread
      for (var p = 0; p < spread.pages.length; p++) {
          var page = spread.pages[p];
          
          // Loop through all text frames on the page
          for (var i = 0; i < page.textFrames.length; i++) {
              var textFrame = page.textFrames[i];

              // Check if the target phrase exists in the content of the
              // text frame
              if (textFrame.contents.indexOf(targetPhrase) !== -1) {
                  // The phrase exists in this text frame
                  pageNumber = page.name
                  // Make sure the result array does not contain duplicates
                  if (!results.contains(pageNumber)) {
                      results.push(pageNumber)
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}


// The phrase we're searching for is defined as whatever the user has selected
var targetPhrase = getSelectedText();

var results = findPageNumbersOfOccurancesOfText(targetPhrase);

// Format the result array as something like `1, 2, 3, 4`
var resultsJoined = results.join(', ')

// Print the formatted results on an alert dialog, for instant feedback
alert(resultsJoined)

// Copy the formatted results into clipboard, so that the user can paste it
// where he needs it
copyToClipboard(resultsJoined)
```